# Count of CloudFront's Invalidation Requests

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, cache-invalidation

I used `*` wildcard to clear everything and now wish to check the total number of invalidation requests made. How can I know that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are asking so that you are aware of whether you've crossed the threshold of the free monthly allowance, then may not know that when you send an invalidation request for `*`(or `/*`, the leading slash is implied if not provided) then no matter how much content was actually evicted, the number of invalidation requests you made is only 1.

> The charge to submit an invalidation path is the same regardless of the number of objects you're invalidating: a single object (`/images/logo.jpg`) or all of the objects that are associated with a distribution (`/*`).
>
> — http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Invalidation.html

If you are asking how many objects were actually invalidated, that's not a question that actually has an answer.  Invalidations are operation that removes all versions of all matching objects from all of the edge caches, if present, but they don't get counted as the process is happening.

Comment: Ok! And what about if I put in only '/' ?

Comment: I suspect that would only invalidate the root page of the site, since that's the only thing it could logically mean, though I'm not sure why you ask... hopefully my answer has not caused confusion... Invalidating `*` invalidates all cached content for the distribution, but it's only counted as a single invalidation request.

Comment: Ok, understood. Thanks